# How can I use user claims to limit user access to certain items in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, claims-based-identity

I have a WPF client application, and an ASP.NET WebApi 2.2 server application. The latter also hosts an Authorisation Server, and issues a bearer token to the user on successful login. This is also where the user's claims are added to their Identity object, and are thus included in the bearer token issued via a response header.

If I wanted to limit the user's choice of Branches to work with, would I add one claim for each branch included or excluded from his permitted Branches, or do I create a special claim type, inherited from `IdentityUserClaim`, that is more specific to this application, and encapsulates its own list of Branches, in the one claim? The latter seems to me better OOD and adheres more to the Single Responsibility Principal.

Comment: Do you have control of all processes? If yes you can add some claim with ID or info about the acl or rights this user has, and after some request, bring only the branches he's supposed to access.

Comment: You mean use a plain query, granted auth by a claim, to request acessible branches for that user?

Comment: Sort adding some ID to user's claims. The way I do is: during authentication I add to my "InMemory" the user group. And when mounting resources I use this group flag. Before know [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) I wrote my auth method and when authenticating I set the user's claims based on what I want to get from it during the authenticated request process.

Comment: I suggest you having a look at IdentityServer3, but to illustrate what I am saying, take a look at [my project](https://github.com/vagnerlucas/AuthProvider) and see the `ExternalClaims` property. I think that would help you. If you can get It, I'll try to explain as answer.